# What is default timezone in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, timezone, yii2

I have my local system timezone `Asia/Calcutta` but when I use `date_default_timezone_get()` function in Yii Framework it returns me `UTC`.

The same function returns me `Asia/Calcutta` when I use in my `test.php` file.

What is the problem?

Comment: @skypjack Thanks for making my question more clear.. !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the documentation:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html#getTimeZone%28%29-detail

It explains that "If time zone is not configured in php.ini or application config, it will be set to UTC by default."

Answer (score 3):

For Yii 2, If time zone is not configured in `php.ini` or application config, it will be set to `UTC` by default, as `yii\base\Application`:

```
if (isset($config['timeZone'])) {
    $this->setTimeZone($config['timeZone']);
    unset($config['timeZone']);
} elseif (!ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    $this->setTimeZone('UTC');
}
```

#### How to set timezone for Yii 2

You could set default timezone for Yii2 application in config:

```
$config = [
    'timeZone' => 'Asia/Calcutta',
    'components' => [
    // ...
```

> [Yii2 Applications > timeZone](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-applications#timeZone)

Comment: I am using timeZone' => 'UTC', in my config and when i print echo date_default_timezone_get(); in frontend index file It gives me Asia/Calcutta.

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_get()
```

is a php built-in function.
yii2 sets the the timezone to the timezone setted in the config. Raw php does NOT so the default timezone of the server is being fetched